# Glass bed is higher in center when corners are leveled

Tags: bed-leveling, adhesion

After leveling the corners of my bed (Ender 3 Pro, with Creality glass bed) the center of my bed is higher. When I start a print the nozzle is so close to the glass bed no filament is laid down.

Is there any way to independently level the center of my bed? No matter how much I adjust the knobs I can't get the center leveled.

---

*I bodged it to print the first layer nicely by simply using a raft. Its working for the benchy I am currently printing, but I don't know how feasible a whole beds' worth of parts is on a massive raft. But for the time being this should work for now.*

Comment: Possibly related: [Why is the center of my glass print bed lower than the corners?](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/9973/why-is-the-center-of-my-glass-print-bed-lower-than-the-corners?rq=1)

Comment: Make sure that the glass is straight, use a ruler on its side to see it you have a bump in the glass when the sheet of glass is not on the printer, but, flat on the table.

Answer (score 1):

If the glass is not straight you can do 3 things:

- use a bltouch or some other mesh level mechanism.
- adjust the height for the center of the bed, so you can print small prints with no problem. Do this by leveling the 4 corners and then adjusting all 4 knobs the same amount until the center is at the correct height.
- probably the best thing to do is get a new glass plate. Creality has more issues with warped or bulged print-surfaces. Maybe your supplier can take care of this for you.

Comment: Do you think its worth reaching out to Creality about? Or should I just look into other hobbyist grade glass beds and use a purple glue stick?

Comment: Your bed really needs to be flat. Reach out to creality about the issue.